# Azure Offline Sync

Tags: c#, azure, azure-mobile-services

Working with an Azure app service offline sync with .net backend. It is working totally fine but when i directly remove a row from the server database it does not sync (updated) after clicking refresh button on the mobile app but if i edit any name attribute it sync automatically after clicking the refresh button. As far as i know it should also automatically update the mobile list if i delete any row from server database as it updates after any row is edited. **Any Help! so i can make it work proper if a row is deleted from database then after refreshing it shows new updated database list?**

Following is the toDoactivity.cs class

```
 public class ToDoActivity : Activity
{
    //Mobile Service Client reference
    private MobileServiceClient client;

    //Mobile Service sync table used to access data
    private IMobileServiceSyncTable<ToDoItem> toDoTable;

    //Adapter to map the items list to the view
    private ToDoItemAdapter adapter;

    //EditText containing the "New ToDo" text
    private EditText textNewToDo;

    const string applicationURL = @"https://my2doservice.azurewebsites.net";        

    const string localDbFilename = "local.db";

    protected override async void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);

        // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Activity_To_Do);

        CurrentPlatform.Init();

        // Create the Mobile Service Client instance, using the provided
        // Mobile Service URL
        client = new MobileServiceClient(applicationURL);
        await InitLocalStoreAsync();

        // Get the Mobile Service sync table instance to use
        toDoTable = client.GetSyncTable<ToDoItem>();

        textNewToDo = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.textNewToDo);

        // Create an adapter to bind the items with the view
        adapter = new ToDoItemAdapter(this, Resource.Layout.Row_List_To_Do);
        var listViewToDo = FindViewById<ListView>(Resource.Id.listViewToDo);
        listViewToDo.Adapter = adapter;

        // Load the items from the Mobile Service
        OnRefreshItemsSelected();
    }

    public async Task InitLocalStoreAsync()
    {
        // new code to initialize the SQLite store
        string path = Path.Combine(System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal), localDbFilename);

        if (!File.Exists(path)) {
            File.Create(path).Dispose();
        }

        var store = new MobileServiceSQLiteStore(path);
        store.DefineTable<ToDoItem>();

        // Uses the default conflict handler, which fails on conflict
        // To use a different conflict handler, pass a parameter to InitializeAsync. For more details, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=521416
        await client.SyncContext.InitializeAsync(store);
    }

    //Initializes the activity menu
    public override bool OnCreateOptionsMenu(IMenu menu)
    {
        MenuInflater.Inflate(Resource.Menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    //Select an option from the menu
    public override bool OnOptionsItemSelected(IMenuItem item)
    {
        if (item.ItemId == Resource.Id.menu_refresh) {
            item.SetEnabled(false);

            OnRefreshItemsSelected();

            item.SetEnabled(true);
        }
        return true;
    }

    private async Task SyncAsync(bool pullData = false)
    {
        try {
            await client.SyncContext.PushAsync();

            if (pullData) {
                await toDoTable.PullAsync("allTodoItems", toDoTable.CreateQuery()); // query ID is used for incremental sync
            }
        }
        catch (Java.Net.MalformedURLException) {
            CreateAndShowDialog(new Exception("There was an error creating the Mobile Service. Verify the URL"), "Error");
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            CreateAndShowDialog(e, "Error");
        }
    }

    // Called when the refresh menu option is selected
    private async void OnRefreshItemsSelected()
    {
        try
        {
            await SyncAsync(pullData: true); // get changes from the mobile service
            await RefreshItemsFromTableAsync(); // refresh view using local database
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
               CreateAndShowDialog(e, "Error");
        }
    }

    //Refresh the list with the items in the local database
    private async Task RefreshItemsFromTableAsync()
    {
        try {
            // Get the items that weren't marked as completed and add them in the adapter
            var list = await toDoTable.Where(item => item.Complete == false).ToListAsync();

            adapter.Clear();

            foreach (ToDoItem current in list)
                adapter.Add(current);

        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            CreateAndShowDialog(e, "Error");
        }
    }

    public async Task CheckItem(ToDoItem item)
    {
        if (client == null) {
            return;
        }

        // Set the item as completed and update it in the table
        item.Complete = true;
        try {
            await toDoTable.UpdateAsync(item); // update the new item in the local database
            await SyncAsync(); // send changes to the mobile service

            if (item.Complete)
                adapter.Remove(item);

        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            CreateAndShowDialog(e, "Error");
        }
    }

    [Java.Interop.Export()]
    public async void AddItem(View view)
    {
        if (client == null || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(textNewToDo.Text)) {
            return;
        }

        // Create a new item
        var item = new ToDoItem {
            Text = textNewToDo.Text,
            Complete = false
        };

        try {
            await toDoTable.InsertAsync(item); // insert the new item into the local database
            await SyncAsync(); // send changes to the mobile service

            if (!item.Complete) {
                adapter.Add(item);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            CreateAndShowDialog(e, "Error");
        }

        textNewToDo.Text = "";
    }

    private void CreateAndShowDialog(Exception exception, String title)
    {
        CreateAndShowDialog(exception.Message, title);
    }

    private void CreateAndShowDialog(string message, string title)
    {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

        builder.SetMessage(message);
        builder.SetTitle(title);
        builder.Create().Show();
    }
}
```

Comment: Please set breakpoint after ` await client.SyncContext.PushAsync();
` in the method SyncAsync. Check whether the PullAsync is called.

Comment: PullAsync is called but it shows already fetched database in it's local db file which is populated on running the application first time. Even it contains the directly deleted row from the server databse.

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to turn on soft delete on the server. Add the following in your server initialization code:

```
DomainManager = new EntityDomainManager<TodoItem>(context, Request, enableSoftDelete: true);
```

Soft Delete allows you to notify your clients that a record has been deleted. When you delete a record, it’s just marked as deleted. That allows other clients to download the new state and update their offline sync cache.

To learn more, see [30 Days of Zumo.v2 (Azure Mobile Apps): Day 19 – ASP.NET Table Controllers](https://shellmonger.com/2016/05/11/30-days-of-zumo-v2-azure-mobile-apps-day-19-asp-net-table-controllers/).

Comment: this link is really helpful but it's in node.js backend. Is there any same blog with .net backend?

Comment: @AizazAthar Check again, my answer and the blog post is for the .NET backend.

Comment: ah my bad! Thanks. Now a days i'm working on offline sync to integrate it with my original project. Will surely ping you when i stuck somewhere.